VS Code Serial Monitor Not Working but Other Serial Monitors Work Fine?
I have a raspberry pi pico running a simple hello world program (below). When I run the program on the pico and look at VS code's built in serial monitor, nothing happens. However, when I look at the arduino IDE's serial monitor, I see a bunch of "Hello, world!"'s as I should. This works similarly in the PUTTY serial monitor.
Pi Pico code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
    while (true) {
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}


I have tried adjusting baud rates to no success. When I power off the raspberry pi pico, the serial terminal in VS code closes, so I know that there is some sort of connection and VS code isn't just looking at the wrong com port somehow.

I've not used that tool, but you have "Line ending" set to "None". So it may just be buffering the data. Try changing that setting.

Thanks for the suggestion! I tried changing it and had the same problem. In the Arduino IDE serial monitor (where it does work), "line ending" is also set to "None" too

I had the same issue with no text on terminal.
I succeed by clicking on the checkbox option DTR...
Strange but successfull.
